# XSLT - Error accessing Java object while Iterating List

Tags: java, object, xslt

I have the below XML payload

```
<Info>
    <Details>
        <Name>Sherlock Holmes</Name>
        <Address>221b Baker St</Address>
        <City>London</City>
    </Details>  
</Info>
```

Java POJO as below:

```
package java:com.sample.domain;

public class AResponse {

    private String code;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

In a separete class method, I have an ArrayList populated with AResponse object with codes

ArrayList : 'aList' is passed with objects with code values as K1, J4, B3

I want to construct the below payload by iterating the aList and construct  element tag

```
<Info>
    <Results>
        <Code>K1</Code>
        <Code>J4</Code>
        <Code>B3</Code>
    </Results>
    <Details>
        <Name>Sherlock Holmes</Name>
        <Address>221b Baker St</Address>
        <City>London</City>
    </Details>  
</Info>
```

I have tried the below XSLT, but I get the error at start up: 
XsltErrorListener:  Fatal error parsing XSLT file: Cannot find a 1-argument function named Q{java:com.sample.domain.AResponse}getCode(). External function calls have been disabled;

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.openuri.org/mySchema" xmlns:list="java.util.List" 
xmlns:a="java:com.sample.domain.AResponse">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/|@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:param name="aList" />

     <xsl:template match="Info"> 
        <xsl:element namespace="http://www.openuri.org/mySchema" name="Results">
            <xsl:for-each select="$aList">
            <xsl:variable name="aResp" select="." />
            <xsl:element namespace="http://www.openuri.org/mySchema" name="Code">
                 <xsl:value-of select="a:getCode($aResp)" />                
            </xsl:element> 
            </xsl:for-each>  
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which version, which edition do you use there with Java?

Comment: I am using Apache camel - Java DSL with 'camel-core' dependency version -  '2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1' . From Camel route I invoke the XSLT using ".to("xslt:com/transform/aResponse.xsl?contentCache=false") "

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks like this is Saxon, and the message says that external function calls have been disabled. So we need to see how you are invoking the transformation. External function calls are not disabled by default, so it must be something you are doing in the invocation.

Comment: Thanks for responding Micheal. I am using Apache camel - Java DSL with 'camel-core' dependency version - '2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1' . From Camel route I invoke the XSLT using ".to("xslt:com/transform/aResponse.xsl?contentCache=false")